# Using multiple booleans as value for selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf

I have a number of Booleans that I want to group together by using a h:selectManyCheckbox. I don't want the value to be an ArrayList or Array, just my XX Boolean fields. Is there anyway this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Just use [`<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectBooleanCheckbox.html) for each.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.boolean1}" />
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.boolean2}" />
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.boolean3}" />
...
```

Comment: Yeah I figured. The problem is I want to perform required-validation and render various things when any of them are checked. Which would lead to some ugly code (#{this or that or theother} etc.). But thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah I tried to do some kind of smart mapping, but I'm unsure of how to do it. Tried using a List<Boolean> but that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but in case someone (like I was) still looking for the answer

Using Java 8:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.checks}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value1" itemLabel="Label 1" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value2" itemLabel="Label 2" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value3" itemLabel="Label 3" />  
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Bean:

```
private List<String> checks;
private Map<String, Runnable> checksMap;

private void initMap() {
  checksMap = new HashMap<>();
  checksMap.put("value1",   () -> myentity.setBoolean1(true));
  checksMap.put("value2",   () -> myentity.setBoolean2(true));
  checksMap.put("valueN",   () -> myentity.setBooleanN(true));
}
```

When you save your entity, just iterate over the choosen checks, and set your booleans according to checksMap:

```
checks.stream().forEach( (e) -> checksMap.get(e).run() );
```